# Trouble redefining div height in slidedown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble with redefining the height property of  a div that acts as a background for a dropdown menu. The idea is that when you click on an item in the list, the nested list and background div slide out, and then if you click on another item in the main list, the first nested list and background div slide up, the new list and the background div then slide down. My touble is that the background div height isn't getting redefined, and it keeps the height of the first list. Here's my jquery:

```
    $(function() {

    $( "ul.hmenu li a" ).click(function() {

        var parentUlHeight = $("ul.hmenu").outerHeight(true) - 1;
        var newUlHeight, oldUlHeight;

        // REMOVE OLD SELECTION
        $(".currentSelection").siblings('ul').slideUp("fast"); //find old selection and slide up its sibling ul
        oldUlHeight = $(".currentSelection").siblings('ul').height();
        $('#subnavdiv').slideUp("fast");
        $(".currentSelection").removeClass("currentSelection"); //remove the class from the old selection


        // MAKE NEW CURRENT SELECTION
        $(this).addClass("currentSelection");
        newUlHeight = $(".currentSelection").siblings('ul').height(); //calc height of new current selection subnav
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown("slow");

        // ANIMATE DIV BACKGROUND
        $('#subnavdiv').css( "top", parentUlHeight + "px" ); //position div at right height

        $('#subnavdiv').height( newUlHeight ); // set height to new selection height -- NOT WORKING
        $('#subnavdiv').slideDown("slow");

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav clearfix desktop-nav" style="left: 146px;">
    <ul class="hmenu">
        <li class="item-103 current active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li class="item-105 deeper parent">
            <a href="#">Our Team</a>
            <ul class="hmenu-left-to-right" style="">
                <li class="item-145">link</li>
                <li class="item-146">link</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="subnavdiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#subnavdiv {
width: 900px;
background: #607852;
display: none;
position: absolute;

-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}
```

Any Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I had made something similar a while back, you could check  if this helps : http://jsfiddle.net/zcQRV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close to what you're looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/F9De4/

you might instead add a class name `".main-link"` to your anchor tag instead of `"ul.hmenu li a"`

```
$(".main-link").toggle(function(){

    var newUlHeight = $(this).parent().find(".hmenu-left-to-right").height();

    $(this).parent().find(".hmenu-left-to-right").hide("fast");

    $('#subnavdiv').hide();

    $("#subnavdiv").css("height",newUlHeight);
    $('#subnavdiv').slideDown("slow");

},function(){

    var newUlHeight = $(this).parent().find(".hmenu-left-to-right").height();
    $(this).parent().find(".hmenu-left-to-right").show("fast");

    $('#subnavdiv').hide();

    $("#subnavdiv").css("height",newUlHeight);
    $('#subnavdiv').slideDown("slow");

});
```